# How much should I include (or index) alongside a full-text-search column in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Sorry for the vague title, I couldn't think of how to more clearly word this in English.

## My goal

To search through individual subtitles for ssome text, and have my program show a list of results, with each result being the text of the subtitle that matched, the video/audio file it's associated with, the timestamp of the matching subtitle, and -- crucially -- the text of the previous and next 3 subtitles, for context.

## What I've done so far

I've achieved a fast, perfectly-behaved search for individual matching subtitles, just not the previous-and-next-3 for context.

I have a SQLite 3 database with two tables.

- `media_files` is a regular old table with `"id" integer primary key, "path" text unique`, and an index on `"path"`.
- `subtext` is a full-text-search (FTS5) virtual table with columns `"text", "start_secs", "media_file_id" unindexed`. `"start_secs"` is always the positive integer timestamp at which the subtitle appears. `"text"` is the column I want to search.

My search query is

```
SELECT
    subtext.text,
    subtext.start_secs,
    media_files.path
FROM subtext
JOIN media_files
    ON subtext.media_file_id = media_files.id
WHERE subtext.text MATCH ?;
```

## What I've attempted

In order to try and get the 3 subtext.text values on either side of my matching subtext row, I tried:

```
WITH ranked_subtext AS (
    SELECT
        subtext.text,
        subtext.start_secs,
        media_files.path,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY subtext.start_secs) AS row_num
    FROM subtext
    JOIN media_files ON subtext.media_file_id = media_files.id
    WHERE subtext.text MATCH ?
)
SELECT
    rs.text,
    rs.start_secs,
    rs.path,
    prev.text AS prev_text_1,
    LAG(rs.text, 1) OVER (ORDER BY rs.start_secs) AS prev_text_2,
    LAG(rs.text, 2) OVER (ORDER BY rs.start_secs) AS prev_text_3,
    next.text AS next_text_1,
    LEAD(rs.text, 1) OVER (ORDER BY rs.start_secs) AS next_text_2,
    LEAD(rs.text, 2) OVER (ORDER BY rs.start_secs) AS next_text_3
FROM ranked_subtext rs
LEFT JOIN ranked_subtext prev ON rs.row_num = prev.row_num + 1
LEFT JOIN ranked_subtext next ON rs.row_num = next.row_num - 1;
```

However, this takes over an hour per query at least, where the no-context example took under a second.

I'm not entirely sure where the problem is here, this is my first time ever using `LAG`, `LEAD`, or full-text-search. The column I'm ordering by is indexed. I'm sure I'm doing something dumb, and I'd be very grateful if someone could point it out to me.

Am I not supposed to do things like this with an FTS table? Would it be better to have a second traditional table for subtitles, an FTS table just to get the id of a matching row in that table, and then query the traditional table for the previous and next? Maybe I should have `subtext.text` *already* contain the previous and next 3 bits of text? (Inconvenient if I want to shrink or widen that window, and would inflate the size of the database, but make querying simpler...)